# Excel VBA - how to have a right click context menu on all workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba

context menus must be set in the worksheet. is there a way to place it in the personal.XLSB workbook to somehow add a permanent additional right click menu no matter what workbook I have open?

My end goal:
have several computers personal.XLSB reference a workbook with standard right click menu options so I can add this functionality to dozens of computers.

Comment: Add code to the Personal workbooks `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: Or create an add-in and have people run it from it's location rather than copy it to their own folder.

Comment: as far as I know context menus must be set in the worksheet so just adding the macro in the Workbook_Open doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of a workaround I think...

I have a Master xlsm file, and in it I have all the subroutines for creating and deleting my context menus.

Then let's say I've got...

ThisFile

ThatFile

AnotherFile
which I want to use the same context menus from Master...

In each one, I've just added this to Workbook_Open:

```
Application.Run "Master.xlsm!AddContextMenuEntries"
```

You need to have Master open for it to work (which is just another line of code if need be).

But now if I edit/change/update the context Menus in Master, they'll be available to all the other files when I reopen them.

Hope that helps.